# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space: Parsing dblp.xml

Tags: java, xml, macos, out-of-memory

I am using `mac 10.5.8` and `Java 1.5`. I am trying to parse a big file: `dblp.xml`. I am following the instructions in this link in order to get the file parsed using SAX: > http://www.informatik.uni-trier.de/~%20ley/db/about/simpleparser/index.html . I should run the code using the Mac Terminal. Here are the commands:

```
javac Parser.java

java -mx900M -DentityExpansionLimit=2500000 Parser dblp.xml > out.txt
```

Unfortunately, I got the the following exception:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager$ScannedEntity.<init>(XMLEntityManager.java:2437)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1117)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:905)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:843)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEntityReference(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1334)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1756)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:368)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:834)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:148)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1242)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:375)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:311)
    at Parser.<init>(Parser.java:152)
    at Parser.main(Parser.java:179)
mohammed-al-refais-macbook:src mohammedal-refai$ export JVM_ARGS="-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"
mohammed-al-refais-macbook:src mohammedal-refai$ java -mx900M -DentityExpansionLimit=2500000 Parser dblp.xml > out.txt
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager$ScannedEntity.<init>(XMLEntityManager.java:2437)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1117)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:905)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:843)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEntityReference(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1334)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1756)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:368)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:834)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:148)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1242)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:375)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:311)
    at Parser.<init>(Parser.java:152)
    at Parser.main(Parser.java:179)`

Although the instructions in the link provided showed that it would be parsed with Java 1.5 without problems, I am still having that Exception. Could anyone please help me solve this problem. Your assistance would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are allocating not enough memory to the jvm.

I guess you set your parameter wrong because it is `-Xmx900M` and not `-mx900M`. The 'X' stands for non standard options.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html

Comment: I changed the parameter. Unfortunately, I still have the same Exception.

Comment: Than higher the provided maximum heap space. -Xmx2g

Comment: It is still running. I will let you know the results. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thank you very much, Andreas. I got the file parsed with the maximum heap space. -Xmx2g . Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you please let me know how to increase heap size and how to use the command -Xmx2g?